# string as a return value in c++ function

Tags: c++, string, function, return-value

This is a basic question, but I don't understand this to it fullest.
When I have a function like:

```
string func(){
        string result;
        result = "resultString";

        return result;
}
```

Is this ok or is the string result only a local variable (can go out of scope) ?

If it is ok, why ? Is this a return by value ?

What types in c++ are returned by value, what by reference ?

Comment: Google for: [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), move semantics and return by value

Comment: What you are doing is fine.  Everything is return by value in C++.

Comment: @LukePark except for returning a reference.

Comment: The reference is actually copied in memory when it is returned, like a pointer.  *Technically* speaking, you are still returning a value.

Comment: @LukePark But semantically, it is a reference, an alias for another object. It is nothing like returning a pointer.

Comment: I'm more comparing with how languages like Java handle references. In C++ you are still returning a new reference when you return a reference, it is copied, just like other values.  I'm merely being picky, please ignore me. :)

Comment: @LukePark It would be fine if you were picky while not being wrong. In C++ context this is, as juanchopanza stated, something that's semantically not a value. After that we get into implementation details, which aren't IMHO helpful here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I understand that it is semantically not a value.  But the way it is returned is no different.

Comment: @LukePark it is different as specified in the C++ Standard. It might be implemented the same way as e.g. pointer return, but *might not* as well. The semantical difference is important for optimizations, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this ok or is the string result only a local variable ?

This is perfectly fine. A value is returned, though it might be subject to NRVO.

> If it is ok, why ? Is this a return by value ?

Yes. You wrote `string` as a return type, and that means a value.

> What types in c++ are returned by value, what by reference ?

In C++ you have fine control over that. `string f();` means a function returning a value of type `string`. `string& f();` returns a reference to such value.

Answer (score -1):

> If it is ok, why ? Is this a return by value ?

As an addition to previous answer, I'd say that result is a local variable; as func() prototype specify that return is by value, not reference, c++ compiler will actually call std::string copy constructor to initialize func() return value with a copy of result local variable (beware that if no copy constructo is provided by your code, c++ compiler will create one, which only realizes shallow copy)

Comment: Copy constructor may not be called due o NRVO or move semantics. By the fact in the code above most probably it won't be called.

Comment: That's right copy constructor will not allways be called, it depends on compiler behaviour.